# How to get product data into iOS application where website is already there with Shopify?

Tags: ios, objective-c, html-parsing, data-extraction

Is it possible to get data from online shopping sites(e.g. shopify.com) and render those data into your iOS application, The Only way that I can see is via HTML Parsing, any another approach, Suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

you have to create web Apis, that can fetch data from webSite data base and send that to ios App site> then ios app developer can handle web service data. thats it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir but is there any other method to fetch the data through PHP,  because we are not sure about the database.